# Error in adding new user in Moodle 3.5

Tags: php, mysql, moodle, user-accounts

I'm working with moodle 3.5 and when attempting to add a new user I keep getting this error:

[image]

Comment: What information do you get if you click "More information about this error"?

Comment: This is the link https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/error/debug/codingerror. Nothing mentioned there solved the issue

Comment: Have you installed a custom plugin/module/etc... or you are running a vanilla instalation? Have you tried deleting the cache folder from moodledata? (cd /path/to/moodledata/   rm -rf ./cache/

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Moodle ([Moodle coding error](https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/error/debug/codingerror))

> Coding errors (or coding_exceptions) are problems that are probably caused by incorrect code. For example a plugin that does not communicate correctly with Moodle core.

This means we need some more troubleshooting to figure out what is causing it.

- Was it working fine before? You might have installed a plugin
  recently that is causing this error, try removing the recent plugin.
- Were you using a earlier version then recently upgraded to 3.5?
- Are you able to access the user default preferences page?
  https://you_own_host/moodle/admin/settings.php?section=userdefaultpreferences
- Are you able to access the custom user profile fields?
  https://you_own_host/moodle/user/profile/index.php
- Do you have custom profile fields in the above section? Have you tried removing them, if possible?

You can try clearing the cache at those 2 locations:

- Site Administration -> Development -> Purge all caches
- rm -rf /path/to/moodledate/cache/

You can enable more debug details by editing your config.php and uncommenting the section 7 debug lines:

```
//=========================================================================
// 7. SETTINGS FOR DEVELOPMENT SERVERS - not intended for production use!!!
//=========================================================================
//
// Force a debugging mode regardless the settings in the site administration
// @error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
// @ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
// $CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
// $CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
```

If you still get an error after all this, could you update your question with the extra debug info?